# Error while using Chromedriver in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I need to test a project with capybara, selenium webdriver and chromedriver-helper, but I always get the following error message.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:
   session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

Curren Versions:
capybara - 2.15.4
selenium-webdriver - 3.13.0
chromedriver-helper - 2.0.0

I tried to use other versions of all this gems, but I don't get the error fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my gemfile to use google-chrome successfully:

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'
```

Webdrivers gem will automatic download chromedriver that corresponds you your chrome version. Here is the [link to gem](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers). Hope it will help you